# Javascript: Submit the change for the textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm still a rookie in frontend stuff. I'm searching for quick debugging for JavaScript code in *submitting the change for the **textarea** tag*.

I debugged it with the browser console, but haven't figured how it misbehaved yet. **The desired behavior should be the *Change* button is initially hidden, then when the user starts changing things in the text area, the button appears. And after the button being clicked, it retains the change.**

I tried to look up for similar bugs related to this behavior, but those are neither JavaScript nor exactly related to mine.

Here's the HTML snippet featuring Javascript (I ignore the presentation created by CSS for now):

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Change" id="submitChange" disabled> 
       <textarea id="textChange" rows="10" cols="30" onchange="venueTextChange();"> Write something here </textarea>
        <script>
            function venueTextChange(){
                        var val document.getElementById("textChange").disabled;
                        document.getElementById("submitChange").disabled = !val; 
                    };
    </script>
</form>
```

**2nd**: I'm also wondering how to refactor this code, so that I could externalize this script in such a way that the <*textarea*> tag doesn't have to set the function *venueTextChange()* explicitly in the element- I want to hide it, but for this case, I think I have to include the attribute **onchange**.

Maybe, something like *.addEventListener('onchange',... )* in the external .js script could work?

Comment: You have a typo, there is no equal sign between the variable name and the right hand side, ie `val = document...`. And yes you would use addEventListener, but it would be passed `change` instead of `onchange`, you drop the "on" when using addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the `onChange` event only fires when the element has lost focus, i.e. when the user has changed the text and blurred the field:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

You need to use something like `keyup`, or `onInput` in order to have the event fire immediately, and yes - in order to not have to invoke the function on the `onchange` attribute, you can add an event listener to the element from another script.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/25xmka43/

Comment: thanks for an efficient response. Tbh, I think the response rate for JavaScript threads is fastest lol! I've not thought this coming really that quick!

Comment: can you explain the compact syntax of the 2nd parameter in the *.addEventListener()*? I see it looks like the closure, but what is the arrow pointer meant syntactically?

Comment: @Goldie, that is the syntax for [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the soultion:
just change in venueTextChange() function !val to false.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Change" id="submitChange" disabled> 
       <textarea id="textChange" rows="10" cols="30" onchange="venueTextChange()"> Write something here </textarea>
        <script>
            function venueTextChange(){
                        document.getElementById("submitChange").disabled = false; 
                    };
    </script>
</form>
```